# UTF-8 encoding issue with AJAX responses from Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, utf-8

I know that similar issues where discussed earlier on this page, but none actually solved the issue on the Laravel platform.

I'm having issues with AJAX responses and special charactors, when I open the response URL in the browser the special charactors are displayed properly. The same charactors from the same database data set displayed in the page without AJAXing are displayed correct.

Here is my relevant code (already modified according to other similar issues on different platforms):

```
// Ajax call to add to myevents section
public function addtomyeventsform($eventid){

    $responseArray = array('eventid'=>$eventid);
    $response = Response::view('ajax/sportevent_myevent_add',$responseArray)->header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8');
    return $response; // utf8_encode($response); // that actually made it worse: 4 squares instead of 2 per charactor
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Preview in Chrome:

[image]

I don't understand what is happening here. Anyone can point me in the right direction? Is this Laravel related?

**Addition**

As requested here is the JavaScript code.

```
function addtomyevents(eventid){
    var ajax_url = '/addtomyevents/'+eventid;
    console.log (ajax_url);
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    $('body').css('padding-right','10px');
    $('#form_center').removeClass('hide');
    $('#form_loader').removeClass('hide');

    $.ajax( {
        url:ajax_url,
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#form_container').html(data);
        $('#form_loader').addClass('hide');
        $('#form_container').show('blind', 500);
        setDetailsbutton();
        trackAjax(ajax_url);
     });
 }
```

Comment: What's the meta charset from the page's `<header>`? Is it `<meta charset="UTF-8">`?

Comment: Yes it is: view-source:http://hobbyathletes.com/run/media-maraton-de-cordoba-2015

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers, or just in Chrome? In Chrome if you go to _Menu > More Tools > Encoding_, is it set to **Auto Detect** and does it detect properly the **Unicode (UTF-8)** encoding?

Comment: Also please post the JavaScript code that loads and displays that popup.

Comment: It's the same in other browsers, as I said, the decoding works fine, when loading the page, it's only in the AJAXed parts, that it doesnt encode properly

Comment: By now I've already looked in the sources on your website and found the issue :). I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending the AJAX request from your `addtomyevents` function in the `js/ha_allviews.js` file you have a closure for `beforeSend`. Remove it and it should work:

```
$.ajax( {
    url:ajax_url,
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#form_container').html(data);
    $('#form_loader').addClass('hide');
    $('#form_container').show('blind', 500);
    setDetailsbutton();
    trackAjax(ajax_url);
 });
```

Comment: Great, that's absolutelly correct :-). Well done, thanks very much. Not so sure why I kept that in there in all my AJAX calls. I need to remove that in the other AJAX calls too. Thanks very much!